# The screen of Ubuntu 16.04.01 freezes after login

Tags: 16.04, crash, powerpc

I have managed to install UBUNTU-MATE 16.04.01 in my PowerBook G4. But I have not able to login since the screen gets frozen after typing password and login. I appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: 16.04 no longer receives community support and is off-topic on Ask Ubuntu.  You should install a supported release.

Comment: You can try initial Ubuntu MATE 16.04 from https://releases.ubuntu-mate.org/archived/xenial/ubuntu-mate-16.04-desktop-powerpc.iso for PowerPC instead. And maybe try to find luck on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: FYI:  16.04 was the last release where *flavors* like Ubuntu-MATE provided *ppc* support; main Ubuntu stopped supporting *ppc* in 14.04; however the only support that continued past then is *ppc64el* which your hardware will **not** run.